How can I eliminate the pandas complaint about using aggfunc=np.sum in pivot_tables?
I recently upgraded my pandas from v1.x to v2.x.  However, code that does reasonable things with pivot tables generates an obnoxious set of future warnings.
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 3]], columns=["col1", "col2"])

(Pdb) df
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     2
2    b     3

(Pdb) df.pivot_table(index="col1", values="col2", aggfunc=np.sum)
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: The provided callable <function sum at 0x102bcb2e0> is currently using DataFrameGroupBy.sum. In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly. To keep current behavior pass the string "sum" instead.
      col2
col1      
a        3
b        3

It's that weird FutureWarning that confuses/annoys me.   I am not in fact passing DataFrameGroupBy.sum; I am passing np.sum.  (Maybe behind the scenes the first is an alias for the second). Moreover, I want the callable to be used directly.  That's why I passed it!
Two questions for stackoverflow:
[A] I don't really want to pass the string "sum" here; I think it ought be fine that I pass my own callable.  Is there a right way to do that that I'm not doing?
[B] How can I suppress this specific warning code-wide?
I know how to suppress the warnings for an individual code block using:
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)    

But I use pivot_table everywhere and it would be crazy to use the with context each time.  I could also block FutureWarning's across my codebase, but other FutureWarning's are in fact useful.
How can I suppress this specific warning?

Can you do warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning, module="pandas.pivot_table")?

This question is similar to: How to get rid of specific warning messages in python while keeping all other warnings as normal?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Dana That's only part of the question. The link is certainly helpful though.

Thanks, @wjandrea, for the clarification. Your edit was really helpful

I tried reproducing the warning using Python 3.10 and pandas 2.2.3. After adding the following code the warning disappeared:
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(
    'ignore',
    category=FutureWarning,
    message="The provided callable <function sum"
)

filterwarnings function is set up to catch FutureWarning message, while the other warnings that may come in your code will still be shown
After the question's edit, I dug into the pandas v2.1.0 release notes and found that it now preserves extension dtypes (like Int64 or PyArrow) during reductions, which previously were cast to NumPy dtypes. Now, pandas optimizes methods like DataFrameGroupBy.sum, so using "sum" preserves these optimizations for dtypes like Int64 or Categorical.  However, if you're only dealing with simple numeric data and don't care about extension, using np.sum is fine for now, but expect future behavior changes.


I don't really want to pass the string "sum" here

Why not? It's equivalent.

I think it ought [to] be fine that I pass my own callable

In this case, it doesn't matter, but if you were using a Pandas-specific dtype, it might have to be cast to a lower-level NumPy dtype, which could involve loss of information or different behaviour (though I can't think of any examples off the top of my head).

Moreover, I want the callable to be used directly. That's why I passed it!

This is at the edge of my knowledge, but from what I understand, Pandas hooks into the NumPy protocols, so it may be that using np.sum() on a DataFrameGroupby object will in fact end up calling DataFrameGroupby.sum().

In other words, there's nothing wrong with using "sum" here, based on the info you've provided.

I'm not sure I explained this very well, plus I'm missing details, so if anything's unclear, please LMK.
